# Is there any way to use the ZAP Token Generation and Analysis add-on in an automated way

Tags: security, owasp, zap

I'm trying to automate some security test through ZAP and I would like to know if there is any possible way to use the ZAP Add-on: [Token Generation and Analysis](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/token-generator/) in an automated scenario ?

I checked the Automation Framework add-on but there is not way to add a this task.

And the [API](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/) doesn't show any way as well.

Does anyone know of a solution to analyze a token through ZAP and if not possible of an alternative solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment, no. I can't remember anyone asking for this, but feel free to raise an issue for it: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues

One reason its not available for automation is that right now its a semi-manual process. How would you actually want to automate it?

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for answering this fast.
From what I see now we choose a request in the history of request and can start the plugin.
Maybe if we could have a ZAP API request where we could choose the request.
For now I'm trying to play around with scripting to see how I can access it but as I am new to ZAP it is quite difficult.

Comment: A better place to ask is the ZAP User Group :) https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users

Comment: Ok, I've asked the question, I'll add a link to it here once it get approved for reference. ty :D

Comment: Its approved :D https://groups.google.com/g/zaproxy-users/c/oGL-erGYaEE/m/BLqjg2BAAgAJ